# image size for retina display

Tags: css, media-queries, retina-display

I am reading up on image quality for retina display and I see I can load a higher quality image for -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2. But my question is how much higher? Say I have a regular image that is 800x600 72dpi - what would the retina image be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double the dimensions. So in your example, it would be 1600*1200.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Would I add a max-width of 800px to the css?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, set the width to be the "normal" width that is being scaled up for the retina display. So in your example, that is 800px.