# How to make retina ready image that can be used on retina and non retina devices

Tags: html, css, retina-display, retina

This is a follow up to the link below

[Preparing the images for retina-ready (web)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341857/preparing-the-images-for-retina-ready-web)

This is clarification, because so many words mean different things to different people. It appears that to have one image that looks good on both retina and non-retina device:

if the image on the screen should be max-width of 400 and max-height of 300, then the image itself should be 800 x 600, with a ppi of 144. Then the file should be highly compressed to minimize its download time.

When you display the image, you force it to its max-width and max-height using css/html code like this:

```
<img src:"imagethatis800x600.jpg" style="width:400px; height:300px;" width="400" height="300" />
```

Is this correct? (I have already resolved that our company won't be using responsive.js or a cdn.)

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach would be to use the `srcset` attribute of `img`. Then you can have images in different device pixels per CSS pixel.

Try to open this page both in a desktop browser and in a phone with a supported browser:
http://www.webkit.org/demos/srcset/

The support is still limited, but will probably be better supported soon:
http://caniuse.com/srcset

Comment: Thanks, but since there isn't a lot of support for srcset (especially in IE) this is not yet a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new responsive images [HTML5 standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/edits.html#the-picture-element). As of July 2014 it's only in [beta builds of browsers](http://alistapart.com/blog/post/testing-responsive-images) yet. But the [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) polyfill is already available.

[This article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/14/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/) explains different use-cases quite well. But what you want here is to simply provide an alternative image for high-resolution (e.g. 'retina') displays:

```
<img srcset="small.jpg 1x, large.jpg 2x"
   src="small.jpg"
   alt="A rad wolf" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For broad browser compatibility you could also use CSS background-images on container elements and control the background file (retina or non-retina) with [media queries / dpi queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LNeC/)

```
#container {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    @media 
      only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
      only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
          background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, am not able to use css backgrounds for this.